# Is there any salesforce trigger that automatically delete record from Azure SQL when records deleted in salesforce object

Tags: salesforce, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I have loaded Salesforce Object data in azure SQL and now I want that if records deleted in Salesforce object then these records should be deleted in Azure SQL also. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, you want to get real-time synchronization between Salesforce and SQL db.

Please evaluate your real situation to consider below two scenarios:

1.If deletions are very frequently. I suggest you logging a list of delete ids so that you could execute a scheduled job in ADF every day to bulk delete corresponding rows in the sql db. Please backup sql db data every day in case any accident occurs.

2.If it is not frequently.
You could considering using [Apex Trigger](https://www.janbasktraining.com/blog/what-is-trigger-in-salesforce/) in Salesforce.Once data is deleted in Salesforce, delete corresponding row in sql db based on the `Id`. Please see below threads:

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/268229/apex-trigger-to-callout-rest-api-to-external-system-when-the-status-is-updated

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000092YrIAI

Comment: In first situation how can we get deleted ID's from the salesforce objects and how can we pass those ID's in ADF?
Is there any way to pass that ID's in a blob for perticullar Object in azure blob container?

Answer (score 0):

I would look at Change Data Capture, it offers near realtime synchronization of data which I think fits your use case.  See more details in thedocumentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_intro.htm).  It is events based similar to the streaming api, so your application would have to subscribe to the channel corresponding to the object's change events.